# Accessing a get method in base class from a child class not returning value

Tags: java

I am trying to access radius in Circle from Cylinder. When I call the base class getRadius() method from inside Cylinder, nothing is happening. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong? I'd appreciate it.

Circle class:

```
public class Circle extends Point {
double radius;

Circle(){
    this.radius = 0.0;
}    
Circle(double radius){
    this.radius = radius;
}    
public double getRadius(){
    return radius;
}    
public void setRadius(double radius){
    this.radius = radius;
}    
public double area(){
    double area = Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2);
    return area;
}    
@Override
public String toString(){
    return String.format("Radius: " + radius);
}
}
```

Cylinder class:

```
public class Cylinder extends Circle{
private double height;

public Cylinder(){
    this.height = 0.0;
}
public Cylinder(double height){
    this.height = height;
}
public double getHeight(){
    return height;
}    
public void setHeight(double height){
    this.height = height;
}    
public double volume(double height){
    double volRad = super.getRadius();
    double volume = Math.PI * Math.pow(volRad, 2) * height;
    return volume;
}    
@Override
public double area(){
    double areaRad = super.getRadius();
    double area = Math.PI * Math.pow(areaRad, 2);
    return area;
}    
@Override
public String toString(){
    return String.format("Height: " + height);
}
}
```

Code inside my main() function(ignore the Point code):

```
    double radius = 3.2;
    double height = 5.1;
    Point point = new Point(3, 4);
    Circle circle = new Circle(radius);
    Cylinder cylinder = new Cylinder(height);

    //Print out objects via overridden toString() method
    System.out.println("Point properties: " + point.toString());
    System.out.println("Circle properties: " + circle.toString());
    System.out.println("Cylinder properties: " + cylinder.toString());

    //Invoke area() in circle object
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

    System.out.println("\nCircle area: " + df.format(circle.area()));

    //Invoke area() and volume() in cylinder
    System.out.println("\nCylinder area: " + df.format(cylinder.area()));
    System.out.println("Cylinder volume: " + df.format(cylinder.volume(height)));
```

This is my output:

```
Point properties: X-value: 3 Y-value: 4
Circle properties: Radius: 3.2
Cylinder properties: Height: 5.1

Circle area: 32.17

Cylinder area: 0
Cylinder volume: 0
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: You're not setting the radius for your cylinder ... or in other words: a cylinder is more than just the `height` you're passing to  the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting the value of `radius` for your `Cylinder`, and the 'default' value is 0.0:

```
Circle(){
    this.radius = 0.0;
}
```

You can set it like this

```
Cylinder cylinder = new Cylinder(height);
cylinder.setRadius(some value);
```

Or modify the Cylinder constructor:

```
public Cylinder(double height, double radius){
    super(radius); //call the correct constructor, not the one that set 0.0 as default.
    this.height = height;
}
```

and create the instance like this:

```
Cylinder cylinder = new Cylinder(height, radius);
```

Although, I will like better if you can have [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), and create the instance of a `Cylinder` using a `Circle` (passing this object to the constructor).

Answer (score 1):

The `radius` in your `Cylinder` is 0.0 since you never assign a value to it.
This would help:

```
Cylinder cylinder = new Cylinder(height);
cylinder.setRadius(some value);
```

Better to add a constructor which allows to set radius and height:

```
public Cylinder(double radius, double height){
    super(radius);
    this.height = height;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call setRadius on your Cylinder object, or add a 2 argument constructor (height, radius) to Cyclinder

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor for your `Cylinder` you are not explicitly calling any super constructor of `Circle`. Therefore the default constructor is called implicitly, which sets the radius to 0.

What you want instead is calling the super constructor defining the radius:

```
public Cylinder(double height, double radius){
    super(radius);
    this.height = height;
}
```

Instead of the constructor with the height alone. The default constructor which initializes the hight with 0 is ok, because there the radius does not matter either.